# Reading S3 Sentinel-2 image files with rasterio

Tags: python, remote-sensing, sentinel-2, rasterio, amazon-web-services

I am currently experiencing an 'Access Denied' error after using rasterio to open the Sentinel-2 AWS .jp2 image files (currently hosted by Sinergise and can be found [here](http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com)).

My code looks like this:

```
import rasterio

access_key = '*****************'
secret_access_key = '***********************'
region_name = 'eu-central-1'

Session = rasterio.env.Env(aws_access_key_id=access_key,
             aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key,
             region_name=region_name)

url = 's3://sentinel-pds/tiles/10/S/DG/2015/12/7/0/B01.jp2'

with Session:
    with rasterio.open(url) as dataset:
            print dataset
```

The response is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CPLE_AWSAccessDenied                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4f6da7274649> in <module>()
     12 
     13 with Session:
---> 14     with rasterio.open(url) as dataset:
     15         print dataset

/Users/Barney/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rasterio/__init__.pyc in open(path, mode, driver, width, height, count, crs, transform, dtype, nodata,  **kwargs)
    191         raise ValueError(
    192             "mode string must be one of 'r', 'r+', or 'w', not %s" % mode)
--> 193     s.start()
    194     return s
    195 

rasterio/_base.pyx in rasterio._base.DatasetReader.start (rasterio/_base.c:2847)()

rasterio/_base.pyx in rasterio._base.DatasetReader.start (rasterio/_base.c:2799)()

rasterio/_err.pyx in rasterio._err.CPLErrors.check (rasterio/_err.c:1773)()

CPLE_AWSAccessDenied: Access Denied
```

I'm unsure if I am using rasterio aws environments correctly, is the aws session token key required even if the secret and access keys are provided? I should also add that this function works correctly if provided with a Landsat-8 url (i.e. http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/L8/139/045/LC81390452014295LGN00/LC81390452014295LGN00_B1.TIF)

Versions (installed through Anaconda):

rasterio - 0.36.0

python   - 2.7

Sorry if the above is vague. My questions would be - why does this work for Landsat-8 but not Sentinel-2? How can rasterio be used to open Sentinel-2 AWS data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong bucket name.
It should be `s3://sentinel-s2-l1c`, not `s3://sentinel-pds`

Try:

```
url = 's3://sentinel-s2-l1c/tiles/10/S/DG/2015/12/7/0/B01.jp2'
```

See more info here:
http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/
and
https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/sentinel-2/

Comment: +1 - the [Sentinel-2 on AWS](http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/) specifically states: "LOCATION s3://sentinel-s2-l1c"

Comment: Yep, works with the URL in the answer. Answer should be accepted. Note: access to these JP2 files using free JPEG 2000 drivers has poor performance. You'll need to build GDAL from source using, for example, the not-free MrSID SDK, to get decent performance with JP2. I wonder if there's a reason they went with JP2 instead of GeoTIFF?

Comment: @sgillies Dsoes that mean the rasterio manylinux wheels suffer this performance hit too? Did you by chance do any (public) benchmarks/comparisons?

Comment: I can't distribute the MrSID SDK with the wheels and so they use the free Jasper-based JP2 driver. I don't have benchmarks to publish.